# How do I protect jQuery.get url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi i just want to protect my jQuery.get url (data.php) if any chance to make jQuery.get in class or any else?

my code here here

```
         jQuery.get('data.php', null, function(data) {
                var lines = [];
                traffic = [];
                try {
                    // split the data return into lines and parse them
                    data = data.split(/\n/g);
                    jQuery.each(data, function(i, line) {
                        line = line.split(/\t/);
                        date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                        traffic.push([
                            date,
                            parseInt(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                        ]);
                    });
                } catch (e) {  }
            /// options.series[0].data = traffic;

                //$res = traffic;

            });
```

and i want to protect the url of data.php 
ps: data.php is my side trafic from sql snd im using for highcharts so the the call for hightcharts is

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Stats',
        data: traffic
```

Thanks in advance anyone!

Comment: You can wrap the code in IIFE to make it private.

Comment: ty for the fast reply but haw any exemple?

Comment: You could use an Apache rewriterule to obfuscate the directory structure on your server.

Comment: "Protect" from what?

Comment: i dont want any know the folder of data.php or the resulte of data